# How can one differentiate with respect to variable upperbounds in summations?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, summation

I have been looking at derivatives of the form: $$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{i=1}^{x}f(i).$$
There is a simplification in the definition of such a derivative: $$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{i=1}^{x}f(i)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{x+h}f(i)-\sum_{i=1}^{x}f(i)\right)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\sum_{i=x+1}^{x+h}f(i).$$

This simplification does not seem very useful in practice, however. For a particular derivative I have been looking at, I arrive at: $$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{i=1}^{x}=\lim_{h\to 0}\sum_{i=x+1}^{x+h}\frac{1}{ih}.$$ This seems fruitless. I know, from Wolfram Alpha, that the solution is $\frac{\pi^2}{6}-H_{x,2}$ where $H_{m,n}$ is the generalized harmonic number.

So, I have two questions:

1. How do you, in general, deal with derivatives of the form $\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{i=1}^{x}f(i)$? (It would help to illustrate the tactics with notable examples.)
2. How do you arrive at $\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{i=1}^{x}\frac{1}{i}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-H_{x,2}$?

Edit:
It may be worthwhile to focus on cases where $\sum_{i=1}^{x}f(i)$ does not have a closed form because the derivative reduces to the derivative of a typical function if the summation has a closed form.

Comment: A function $f(n) = \sum_{i=0}^n a(i)$ is only defined at discrete points (integers) and is therefore not differentiable ($\sum_{i=0}^{2.5}$ does not make sense and neither does the derivative). If you want to differentiate it you will first have to define precisely what you mean by $\sum^{x}$ when $x$ is not an integer.

Comment: First of all, harmonic numbers in particular can be evaluated for any value of the argument, by means of a certain [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation). Try differentiating under the integral sign.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you are looking for is a clear definition and some interesting properties for the notation
$$
\sum_{\nu=1}^{x}f(\nu)
$$ where $x$ is **any real number**.

This has been done by Markus Müller and Dierk Schleicher, they have introduced a natural definition for the sum above, **they propose a systematic way to extend summations to non-integer numbers of terms:** [see this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0502109v3.pdf).

They called these sums "fractional sums", of course their work meets the works of Euler and Ramanujan.

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted. It seems like a reasonable reference.

Comment: @martycohen It was just serial downvoting, it has been reversed today. Thank you very much.